# Why do I get the errormessage 'Break outside Loop'?

Tags: python

I just started getting into coding and atm I follow a very basic Pythoncourse. 
The following code is posted as an example of a loop which gets disrupted when the number is equal to 24. Copying this exact code from the course gives me the error ''Break outside loop''.

I tried several combinations of placing the word 'break' on different places, but nothing works. I don't know why.

```
temp = 15


while temp<=30:

     print('It is '+format(temp)+' degrees')

if temp == 24:

      print('It is 24 degrees!')

break

temp+=1
```

I expect the output to print 'It is 24 degrees!', but instead I get break

> SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop.

Comment: Your indentations are wrong. `break` should be inside `while` loop

Comment: Indentation is important in Python. The `if` is outside the `while` and the `break` is outside both, `if` and `while`

Comment: `break` statement must come inside a loop. Yours is outside the `while` loop which is the only one in your program.

Comment: Is that the same indentation as in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're new to python, make sure that it is all about indentation, so you must take that into consideration. Your `break` should be inside the if condition.
I modified your print a little.

The error is telling you that you used break outside the loop. `break` and `continue` are used inside loops.

Look [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/break-continue) for further information about break and continue.
This code works

```
temp = 15
while temp<=30:
    print('It is {} degrees'.format(temp))
    if temp == 24:
        print('It is 24 degrees!')
        break
    temp+=1
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Shadowfax! Very logical how you explain it, and that is perfect for someone like me who just starts out.

Comment: I'm glad that my answer helped you :D Accept it to help others find the answer.